# make: *** [all] Error 2 Install gr ieee802-11

Tags: compiling, gnuradio

```
freedomchen@ubuntu:~/gr-ieee802-11/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_generated_includes
[  3%] Generating moving_average_ff.h, moving_average_cc.h
[  3%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_includes
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_generated_sources
[  6%] Generating moving_average_cc_impl.cc, moving_average_ff_impl.cc
[  6%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_sources
[ 10%] Generating moving_average_cc_impl.h, moving_average_ff_impl.h
Scanning dependencies of target gnuradio-ieee802_11
[ 13%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/moving_average_cc_impl.cc.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/moving_average_ff_impl.cc.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/equalizer/linear_comb.cc.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/equalizer/lms.cc.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/chunks_to_symbols_impl.cc.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ether_encap_impl.cc.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_decode_mac.cc.o
[ 36%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_decode_signal.cc.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc.o
/home/freedomchen/gr-ieee802-11/lib/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc: In member function ‘virtual int ofdm_equalize_symbols_impl::general_work(int, gr_vector_int&, gr_vector_const_void_star&, gr_vector_void_star&)’:
/home/freedomchen/gr-ieee802-11/lib/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc:60:76: error: ‘get_tags_in_window’ was not declared in this scope
   get_tags_in_window(tags, 0, i, i + 1, pmt::string_to_symbol("ofdm_start"));
                                                                            ^
make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
freedomchen@ubuntu:~/gr-ieee802-11/build$ sudo make install
[  3%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_includes
[  6%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_sources
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc.o
/home/freedomchen/gr-ieee802-11/lib/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc: In member function ‘virtual int ofdm_equalize_symbols_impl::general_work(int, gr_vector_int&, gr_vector_const_void_star&, gr_vector_void_star&)’:
/home/freedomchen/gr-ieee802-11/lib/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc:60:76: error: ‘get_tags_in_window’ was not declared in this scope
   get_tags_in_window(tags, 0, i, i + 1, pmt::string_to_symbol("ofdm_start"));
                                                                            ^
make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Sorry, you should [edit] your question and not my answer. And you should run `cmake ..` with the two dots at the end.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install cmake-data` and again `cmake ..`

Comment: got the same results

Comment: Guy, ok, remove the folder `gr-ieee802-11` with `rm -r ~/gr-ieee802-11` and start again. Follow **each step** in my answer in the section `All steps at once`. Line by line

Comment: *Boost required to compile ieee802-11* so you likely need to install the prerequisite `libboost` development components - or try `libboost-all-dev` if you don't know specifically which one(s)

Comment: What's that? How to install? Thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and again `cmake ..`

Comment: I got these new errors.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install swig`

Comment: yes. I have already done this step now. These errors still exist.

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas … :\  Please make a rollback to a previous version. Your current question is totally different to the original version and my answer is therefore useless. Ask a new question with your compiler problem. The Makefile problem is answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this answer, please read the [entire revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/645544/revisions) of OPs question.

---

Follow ***ALL*** steps and not only what you think **;)**

Before you can start `make …`

1. Install the following packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get install swig
   sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
   sudo apt-get install cmake-data
   sudo apt-get install liblog4cpp5-dev
   sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev
   sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
   sudo apt-get install gnuradio-dev
   ```
2. Run `cmake ..` in the `build` folder

---

*All steps at once*

```
cd
sudo apt-get install swig
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake-data
sudo apt-get install liblog4cpp5-dev
sudo apt-get install libitpp-dev
sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev
sudo apt-get install gnuradio-dev
git clone git://github.com/bastibl/gr-ieee802-11.git
cd gr-ieee802-11
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

---

*And here we go*

```
[gr-ieee802-11/build] master ± make
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_generated_includes
[  3%] Generating moving_average_ff.h, moving_average_cc.h
[  3%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_includes
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_generated_sources
[  7%] Generating moving_average_cc_impl.cc, moving_average_ff_impl.cc
[  7%] Built target ieee802_11_generated_sources
[ 10%] Generating moving_average_cc_impl.h, moving_average_ff_impl.h
Scanning dependencies of target gnuradio-ieee802_11
[ 14%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/moving_average_cc_impl.cc.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/moving_average_ff_impl.cc.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/equalizer/linear_comb.cc.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/equalizer/lms.cc.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/chunks_to_symbols_impl.cc.o
[ 32%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ether_encap_impl.cc.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_decode_mac.cc.o
[ 39%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_decode_signal.cc.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_equalize_symbols.cc.o
[ 46%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_mac.cc.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_mapper.cc.o
[ 53%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_parse_mac.cc.o
[ 57%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_sync_long.cc.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/ofdm_sync_short.cc.o
[ 64%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/utils.cc.o
[ 67%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-ieee802_11.dir/wifi_signal_field_impl.cc.o
Linking CXX shared library libgnuradio-ieee802_11.so
[ 71%] Built target gnuradio-ieee802_11
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_swig_swig_doc
[ 71%] Built target ieee802_11_swig_swig_doc
Scanning dependencies of target _ieee802_11_swig_swig_tag
[ 75%] Building CXX object swig/CMakeFiles/_ieee802_11_swig_swig_tag.dir/_ieee802_11_swig_swig_tag.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable _ieee802_11_swig_swig_tag
[ 75%] Built target _ieee802_11_swig_swig_tag
[ 78%] Generating ieee802_11_swig.tag
Scanning dependencies of target ieee802_11_swig_swig_2d0df
[ 82%] Building CXX object swig/CMakeFiles/ieee802_11_swig_swig_2d0df.dir/ieee802_11_swig_swig_2d0df.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ieee802_11_swig_swig_2d0df
Swig source
[ 82%] Built target ieee802_11_swig_swig_2d0df
Scanning dependencies of target _ieee802_11_swig
[ 85%] Building CXX object swig/CMakeFiles/_ieee802_11_swig.dir/ieee802_11_swigPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
Linking CXX shared module _ieee802_11_swig.so
[ 85%] Built target _ieee802_11_swig
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_swig_af2e9
[ 89%] Generating ieee802_11_swig.pyc
[ 92%] Generating ieee802_11_swig.pyo
[ 92%] Built target pygen_swig_af2e9
Scanning dependencies of target pygen_python_02efc
[ 96%] Generating __init__.pyc
[100%] Generating __init__.pyo
[100%] Built target pygen_python_02efc
```

Comment: Thanks. I run the cmake before make, but it still "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Comment: Yes, I think, `cmake` gives you some errors.

Comment: @FreedomChan Install the development libraries as described in my answer.

Comment: @FreedomChan: Additionally, posting the full output in [your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/645544/edit) will help find out what the issue is.

Comment: And install the dev libraries as I said!

Comment: @FreedomChan As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: Yes. I am the first user, not familiar with...  thank your help! I will try follow your steps.  But, I cannot get the results as you....

Comment: Based upon the error message provided these are the steps I'd also suggest.